# RestKit 0.20 -- Multiple query parameters with same name?

Tags: ios, rest, restkit

I have an iOS application making use of RestKit 0.20-rc1 for RESTful services.  I'm trying to perform a GET whereby I am providing multiple query parameters with the same name to retrieve a set of objects of the same type.  For example, my URL would look like:

```
http://mysite.com/rest/myobjects?objID=123&objID=234&objID=345
```

My web service is able to accept a query like this and return the appropriate objects.  My RestKit code on the client looks something like this:

```
NSDictionary *params = ...
RKObjectManager *objMgr = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[objMgr getObjectsAtPath:@"/rest/myobjects" parameters:params success:nil failure:nil];
```

My problem, is that the parameters must be specified as an `NSDictionary`, and I have multiple parameters with the same name.  I tried setting the value in the `NSDictionary` to an `NSArray` containing all of the parameter values, but that did not work.

How do I specify multiple query parameters with the same name in RestKit using this methodology?  Is this just not supported in RestKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it is not going to be possible with the RestKit code you have. You may either:

1. Change the code to allow NSArrays. RestKit is open source at https://github.com/RestKit
2. Ask on the RestKit google group to see how others have worked around this. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/restkit
3. Submit a patch to RestKit and wait for a release that supports what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the query with the parameters in the getObjectAtPath. Meaning create a string with the parameters like this:

`NSString *queryPath = @"getNames?names=bob&names=joe&names=joey";`

and then do this (notice that the `parameters` object here is `nil`):

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:queryPath
                                           parameters:nil
                                              success:nil failure:nil];
```

if you have a problem with the encoding just do this:
`queryPath = [queryPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`