# iOS - RESTKit 0.20 - send multiple query parameters with the same name

Tags: ios, restkit

I am trying to send a GET request using RESTKit that looks like this:
`getNames?names=bob&names=joe&names=joey`
When I try to set the parameters dictionary with the same key names, it don't work. Only the first key and value get sent.
I know there's a question about this from a long time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210694/restkit-0-20-multiple-query-parameters-with-same-name). But there is still no answer, and I was wondering if there's any development on this.

Comment: The question you have mentioned in the link has an accepted answer.

Comment: It does have an answer, but it is not informative and doesn't explain how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. This is the code I use:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:queryPath
                                           parameters:nil
                                              success:nil failure:nil];
```

and the queryPath looks like this: `getNames?names=bob&names=joe&names=joey` and it actually works.
make sure to use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding so that the `&` and `?` will go through properly .